# How do I limit the set of supported applications of an Excel add-in for publishing to AppSource?

Tags: xml, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, appsource

I am trying to publish an Excel add-in to AppSource, which requires me to upload a manifest file in Microsoft Partner Center. After uploading, the manifest passes the checks with the following message:

> Manifest checks passed After analyzing your package, we have
>   determined that your product is currently targeting the following
>   applications and platforms:
>
> - Excel for iPad
> - Excel 2016 for Mac
> - Excel 2013 or later
> - Excel 2016 or later
> - Excel Online
>
> Office applications, platforms, and operating systems are
>   determined by the requirement and APIs specified in the 
>   manifest. For details, see Requirements. We'll validate your
>   product on iOS if you check the iOS check box on product
>   setup and provide your Apple ID.

I tried completing the certification process before, and got back the remark that the add-in does not fully function in Excel 2013. This is expected, since the add-in is using the Excel JavaScript API. According to the documentation (for example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/nl-be/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/excel-add-ins-reference-overview) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets)), the Excel JavaScript API was introduced with Office 2016 and thus runs in Excel 2016 and later on Windows. According to [this part of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/specify-office-hosts-and-api-requirements#set-the-requirements-element-in-the-manifest), I need to account for the use of this API in the Requirements element in the manifest file. I have done this by including the following part in the manifest:

```
<Requirements>
      <bt:Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
            <bt:Set Name="ExcelAPI" MinVersion="1.1"/>
      </bt:Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Still, after analysis the message states the add-in also targets Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you could choose a min version depending on the excel APIs, 1.8 would be a good one so it starts at Excel 2019 support:

```
<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="ExcelAPI " MinVersion="1.8"/>
       </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Comment: The add-in should start at Excel 2016 support, which is why I've included the minimum version 1.1. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets) it's stated that Office 2016 only supports the ExcelAPI 1.1 requirement set.

Answer (score 0):

Did you validate your manifest locally ? I guess there is some problem with your manifest which leads the requirement set doesn't take effect. The link below is about how to validate manifest, it will tell you applications and platforms your addin support after validation completed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-manifest

Below is part of manifest i tried locally, it works well.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this input @MandytMSFT . I have validated the manifest locally, and it passes validation. Local validation also wrongly extracts Excel 2013 as one of the supported platforms: `Acceptance Test Completed: Acceptance test service has finished checking provided add-in. (link: undefined) Based on the requirements specified in your manifest, your add-in can run on the following platforms; your add-in will be tested on these platforms when you submit it to the Office Store: - Excel for iPad - Excel 2016 for Mac - Excel 2013 or later - Excel 2016 or later - Excel Online`

Comment: Could you please try moving the  requirements section to the same place as mine ? I noticed there is <bt:> tag in your sharing, suspect you put the requirement in incorrect place.